# how to customize a c++ list container such that it can hold different types of structs?

Tags: c++, c++11

how to customise a c++ list container such that it can holds different type of struct ?

for example

```
struct A
{
  int a;
  int b;
}

struct B
{
  float a;
  float b;
}


#include <list>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   ...
   ...
   A a;
   a.a = 1;
   a.b = 2;

   B b;
   b.a = 123.444;
   b.b = 11.222;

   List.push_back(a);
   List.push_back(b);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why bother ? Make a parent class with some general methods to extract your data from it and have 2 classes inherit from it with each having their own private data. And use the parent class for the type of the list ofc.

Comment: Either store pointer to base class or use tuple, or re-think design.

Comment: @prgbenz You generally don't put things in a single container that can't be identically accessed. Using a common base class with virtual functions, etc. If you pop an item off the `list`, how would the compiler know whether the structure was `A` or `B` at runtime?

Comment: This smells like an X/Y problem; *why* do you want to put `A`s and `B`s in a single container to start with ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not [polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) and a list of pointers to the objects?
Be careful about object lifetime. The pointers in the list will become invalid once the two objects go out of scope. You can alternatively [dynamically allocate](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/416/) (**new**) the two elements and **delete** them when you're done, then remove them from the list.

Later edit: I get the feeling you are new to C++. After studying dynamic allocation, I recommend you look up smart pointers. They lift the burden of manually managing memory by doing it themselves:

[unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and
[shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

You can use them inside the list instead of naked pointers.

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base(){}
};
struct A : public Base
{
  int a;
  int b;
};

struct B : public Base
{
  float a;
  float b;
};


#include <list>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   ...
   ...
   A a;
   a.a = 1;
   a.b = 2;

   B b;
   b.a = 123.444;
   b.b = 11.222;

   std::list<Base*> l;
   l.push_back(&a);
   l.push_back(&b);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a slight danger that you may get dangling pointers if the objects go out of scope, but other than that +1. One can use a smart pointer to make the code safer, and use new/delete with it.

Comment: @vsoftco I tried to keep the answer as simple as possible, I think the OP is new to C++.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases it makes sense to store different types in a container. C++ supports these use cases with *unions*, but this feature is very basic. I recommend using *boost::variant* instead of *unions* if you really need to store different types in a container. I also recommend using `std::vector` instead of `std::list`, because otherwise it doesn't make much sense to use this optimization.

Here is an example with *boost::variant*:

```
std::vector<boost::variant<A, B>> items;
A a = ...;
B b = ...;
items.push_back(a);
items.push_back(b);
struct get_length : boost::static_visitor<double>
{
    double operator()(const A& f) const { return calc(f.a, f.b); }
    double operator()(const B& b) const { return calc(b.a, b.b); }
    double calc(double a, double b) const { return std::sqrt(a * a + b * b); }
};
for (auto&& item : items) {
    double d = boost::apply_visitor(get_length(), item);
    std::cout << d << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `boost:: any`.  But really, does polymorphism not solve your problem?

Comment: Why not using _boost::variant_ instead of _boost::any_?